# root ユーザーの環境で /usr/local/bin にパスが通っていない理由は？

Tags: linux, centos

CentOS を利用しています。
root になったとき、`/usr/local/bin` にインストールしたコマンドを実行しようとしたのですが、初期状態では PATH が通っていませんでした。

セキュリティ関係かと思うのですが、何か理由があって `/usr/local/bin` に PATH を通していないのでしょうか。ご存知の方いらっしゃいましたらご教授お願いします。

Comment: セキュリティが一番かなぁ。/usr/local/bin/lsと言う名前のコマンドを作ったら、きっと実行しちゃうでしょうね。root権限でなければそんなファイルは作れないとは思いますが。よくあるのはバージョン違いのコマンドがインストールされていて、実は互換性がなくて原因がわかりづらい問題を起こすとか。

Answer (score 9, accepted):

CentOS を離れて商用 UNIX の事情を言うなら

`/usr/bin` や `/bin` はベンダが提供している＝ベンダが動作保証をしているソフトが入っていて
`/usr/local/bin` は野良ビルド (ユーザが自力コンパイルしたソフト) が入っています。
(うちの HP-UX は完全にそういう構成、運用をしてます。
バイナリ提供されたソフトの実行形式だけをインストールするなんてありえないです)

ベンダが提供している `root` で起動していいのはベンダが保証しているソフトのみ、
ってことで `root` の `PATH` には `/usr/local/bin` を含めないほうが良い、という判断らしいです。

セキュリティにうるさい `root` は `ls` の起動ですら `/bin/ls` と打つべし
なんて話を聞いたことがあります (不正な `ls` を絶対に起動させないため) 。
`/usr/local/bin` にあるソフトを `root` で使わざるを得ないときは意識してフルパス打つべし
ってことでしょう。

Answer (score 2):

rootはどのマシンにも絶対にある強力なアカウントなので、

- クラッキングの対象になりやすい
- 操作ミスが致命的なシステムエラーを引き起こす可能性が高い

ことからログイン非推奨になっていると思います。

そのため、rootアカウントはログイン禁止にしておき、root権限が必要な際は
sudoが実行できるアカウントを`/etc/sudoers`（`visudo`で編集します)により定義し
権限を持つユーザーのみが、自分のアカウントとパスワードで、
`sudo` コマンド名
と、sudoコマンドで現在のログインアカウントからそのコマンドのみroot権限で実行するのが一般的になっています。

つまり、ログインしないはずのアカウントなのでPATHの設定も必要無いからだと理解しています。

Comment: `sudo -i`をすればrootの環境設定が使われるので必要ないことはないです。ちなみにUbuntuでrootの`$PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin`です。

Answer (score 1):

バグとして2012年に[レポート](https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=5707)されていますが、なぜかスルーされていますね。

Unix & Linux Stack Exchangeに似たような「[Why does root not have /usr/local in path?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115129/why-does-root-not-have-usr-local-in-path)」という質問があります。これの回答によると、歴史的に`/usr/local`は、公式ソフトウェア(多分`/bin`にあるコマンドなど)にバグがあったりした場合に、それをオーバーライドするためにローカルにインストールした非公式なソフトウェア(修正版や実験的機能を追加した版)を置く場所らしいです。で、rootは権限が強力なので、こういう非公式なものを不用意に実行すべきでないので、デフォルトでrootのPATHには`/usr/local`が含まれていないんだそうです。

Comment: [RHELにもバグレポートがありました](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=587183)。ただ、CentOSのレポートで言及されている、rootとして直接ログインした場合は `/usr/local/bin` が含まれているというのは謎ですね。。

Comment: CentOSのレポートで`/usr/local/sbin`には`sudo -i`でもパスが通ると言っていますがそれも変な感じですね。